# Can I update specific users apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I updated my iPhone app game recently on the App Store.

It works fine for almost everyone.

Two friends said the update has caused their game to crash upon opening.

Is there any way that I can send an update or affect just my friends apps?

If they delete and reinstall, the data will be lost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is to try out a new version on them, see if it fixes their problem, and then release it later as an actual App Store update. There are two easy ways to do that:

- Get their device UDID and make and send them an Ad Hoc build.
- Or, make them TestFlight testers.

Comment: That is brilliant. Thank you very much!